# FCM diagnostics - Firebase connection concerns from a Google Fi user

Tags: android, firebase, security, mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

Last month, I changed mobile providers to Google Fi and got a new Pixel 7 phone. I began having strange network issues (some are outlined below). Today I discovered and ran Firebase FCM diagnostics. I restarted my phone, entered the *#*#426#*#* MMI code, then rinsed and repeated several times. Each time, the status report showed a lot of errors and disconnects.

Here is the most recent FCM diagnostic STATUS screen, capturing everything that happened in the first hour after I turned on the phone:

> 06-13 17:42:47.062 net=-1: Failed connection err:3
> 06-13 17:42:49.879 net=1: Reconnect on network change -1
> DISCONNECTED
> 06-13 17:42:50.11 net=1: Connected
> 06-13 17:43:43.245 net=1: Close err:20 time:53
> 06-13 17:43:43.249 net=0: Reconnect on network change 1
> CONNECTED
> 06-13 17:43:44.036 net=0: Connected
> 06-13 17:45:06.960 net=0: Close err:30 time:82
> 06-13 17:45:07.545 net=0: Connected
> 06-13 17:45:25.215 net=0: Close err:20 time:17
> 06-13 17:45:26.355 net=0: Connected
> 06-13 17:45:27.283 net=0: Received
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
> 0:1686692726056444%8b460216f9fd7ecd
> 06-13 17:45:27.383 net=0: No response to broadcast
> from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
> (id=0:686692726056444%8b460216f9fd7ecd time=72ms
> priority=NORMAL)
> 06-13 17:55:24.447 net=0: Received com.google.android.gm
> 0:O1686693323022306%df98306d0c398feb
> 06-13 17:55:24.548 net=0: Acked com.google.android.gm:0
> 0:O1686693323022306%df98306d0c398feb
> 06-13 17:55:24.563 net=0: Sucessful
> broadcast to com.google.android.gm
> (id=O1686693323022306%df98306d0c398feb time=46ms
> priority=NORMAL)

Under EVENTS, FCM diagnostics shows the following:

> Server Connected
> Host: alt5-mtalk.google.com/2a00:1450:400c:c0b::bc
> Port 5228
> Time connected 1:07:01

Can someone please let me know what these errors, disconnects and reconnects indicate?
Any help to make sense of this would be greatly appreciated

p.s. Here is some additional information about my phone, in case it is somehow helpful:

- The phone was on my home wifi for the first two weeks I owned it. Due to concerns about the wifi, I have not connected the phone to it for several weeks.
- The phone vanished from my car and did not turn up until a day later. When it reappeared, there was a SIM card that did not come with the phone in the second SIM slot. I removed it.
- Whenever I first turn the phone on, it briefly says "No service," then "No SIM card, no service."  The message persists for about ten seconds, then the phone connects to Google FI. Google techs had me erase and reinstall the eSIM today. It did not resolve the problem.
- The Google VPN used to turn on quickly and automatically. Now the VPN does not turn on until several minutes after the phone connects to the network, sometimes not for a full five minutes.
- Although my phone usually shows a 5G connection in the status bar in the upper right hand corner of my screen, when I check the connection status elsewhere, it often says I'm connected through LTE.
- Websites will often say "no network" and refuse to load, although the status bar shows I have a strong 5G signal
- It may be a red herring, but the phone continually reinstalls two "user credentials" I don't recognize. The numbers on the credentials increase sequentially each time I delete them. The latest ones are:

User credentials

-HS2_88
-Installed for Wi-Fi

-HS2_88_0
-Installed for Wi-Fi

Based on their name, I'm guessing the credentials either allow my phone to connect to a hotspot network ([https://actfornet.com/ueditor/php/upload/file/20181229/1546047796563472.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com)), or to Apache HiveServer ([https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Overview](https://stackoverflow.com)), but I've never used either one.